# mysqldump. How to set in this command password?

Tags: mysql, terminal

```
mysqldump -u root -p Databasename > backup.sql
```

How to set in this command password? I need run this command in Python script.
At this time, asking me for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqldump -u root -pPassword Databasename > backup.sql
```

[Read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html) for some basic security info.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on Unix...
`env  MYSQL_PWD=<password> mysqldump -u root -p Databasename > backup.sql`

According to [the mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-security-user.html).